# shell script is visible if checked manually in the path, but says 'No Such File or Directory'

Tags: bash, shell, unix, ssh

Following is the shell function which I execute remotely :

```
softrun() {
source /usr/local/bin/myscript.sh
#/bin/bash /usr/local/bin/myscript.sh
}
```

Command to execute above function stored in 'script1.sh' remotely is :

```
ssh user@host script1.sh softrun
```

But it gives error : No Such File or Directory
I have tried by 'source' & 'bash' method.
When I check manually the shell script exist in the location and is not a symbolic link

Comment: Can you provide an example of how you are attempting to execute this remotely, and the complete error message it gives back?

Comment: @tjm3772  I am executing it using command line : 'ssh user@host script1.sh softrun'

Comment: What is the complete and precise error message that you're getting?

Comment: @Kenster : /home/<user>/transfer/copy/script1.sh: line 56: /usr/local/bin/softrun: No such file or directory

Comment: You're a bit short of a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) but your comments here are good info that you should edit into your question. Offhand it looks like `script1.sh` is looking for `softrun` in /usr/local/bin instead of treating it like a shell function, so you should post some context about how `script1.sh` works (near line 56 according to your error message). You may also want to paste your script into https://shellcheck.net to look for syntax or logical errors.

Comment: @tjm3772 Thanks for the input. I have update certain comments in the question itself. `script1.sh` currently only has `softrun` function. everything else is commented. btw I also noticed instead of `softrun` if I call `python3.6` located in same path - it works i.e.  `script1.sh' calls the python correctly

Answer (score 0):

This isn't how you call a function in bash. You can't just pass a function name into the script. You need this in your **script1.sh** file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

softrun() {
  source /usr/local/bin/myscript.sh
}

$1
```

Notice the `$1` at the end of the file. This is your first argument to the script, which you're passing over ssh, which happens to be your function name. The reason you're getting "No Such File or Directory" error is because in your example ssh thinks that `softrun` is yet another file it's supposed to run after running **script1.sh**

UPDATE. Forgot. I think you'll also need to wrap the script name + its argument into quotes, so ssh thinks it's one single argument and not two files to be executed.